# Split a string by commas but ignore commas within double-quotes using TCL

Tags: csv, tcl

I would like to split the content of a csv file and store it in a list using TCL.
Is there any TCL command recommended to split the string by comma, but ignoring the one within a double code.

For example:
`a, b, "c, d", e, "f, g, h", i`

To split it into:

```
input[0] = a
input[1] = b
input[2] = c, d
input[3] = e
.
.
.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Typically one would use the csv package; the documentation is found [here](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/csv/csv.md) and is quite straightforward. Just do `package require csv` and then you can use `::csv::split` on a csv line.

Answer (score 2):

The `csv::split` command from the [csv package in Tcllib](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/csv/csv.md) is perfect for this.

```
package require csv

set s {a, b, "c, d", e, "f, g, h", i}
set input [csv::split $s]
foreach value $input {
    puts "input\[[incr index]\] = $value"
}
```

This produces this output:

```
input[1] = a
input[2] =  b
input[3] =  c, d
input[4] =  e
input[5] =  f, g, h
input[6] =  i
```

Those extra spaces? Well, they are there in the input data. `string trim` the elements if you want to remove them.